# How to enable alpha blending on DirectX?

Tags: directx, alphablending, blending

How to do this in DirectX?

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

Somehow i just cant seem to get it work. Im using code:

```
d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCCOLOR);
d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCCOLOR);
d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, 1);
d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAFUNC, D3DCMP_GREATEREQUAL);
d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF, (DWORD)50);
d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHATESTENABLE, 1);
```

But it will render my polygon with some sort of ghosted method, i can see through all my polygons! i just want to make the texture with alpha channel to show through those fully transparent pieces of texture. this works with alphatest, but it still shows black edges, so i guess the blending isnt enabled, even though i have set D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE ! What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of SRCCOLOR i needed to use SRCALPHA:

```
d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);
```